# How to upgrade the ring file swift?

Tags: upgrade, openstack, openstack-swift

I am upgrading essax to grizzly.
I noted this note https://lists.launchpad.net/openstack/msg16188.html which said after 1.60 swift would use a new format for the ring, but this note didn't specified how to upgrade the ring file.It just said 
" Once your entire cluster is upgraded, only then upgrade the version
   of swift on the box that builds your ring files (ie where you run
   swift-ring-builder). Upgrading this piece will change the on-disk
   format of your generated ring files. Deploy the new ring files to the
   swift cluster."
But I didn't see anything happen to the ring file after the upgrade,the last modified date of the ring files were still the same.

So how to upgrade the ring file in a safe way?
Is there a way to verify if the ring file is upgraded?

Comment: I also read a post which said to use write_ring to upgrade the ring.swift-ring-builder account.builder write_ring swift-ring-builder container.builder write_ring swift-ring-builder object.builder write_ring          but I am not sure if it works..

Answer (score 4):

You may find the text in Administrator's Guide - [Managing the rings](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/admin_guide.html#managing-the-rings) more clearly.

> Swift 1.6.0 is the last version to use a Python pickle format. Subsequent versions use a different serialization format. Rings generated by Swift versions 1.6.0 and earlier may be read by any version, but rings generated after 1.6.0 may only be read by Swift versions greater than 1.6.0. So when upgrading from version 1.6.0 or earlier to a version greater than 1.6.0, either upgrade Swift on your ring building server last after all Swift nodes have been successfully upgraded, or refrain from generating rings until all Swift nodes have been successfully upgraded.

The newer version can read the old format, so first upgrade all nodes to newer swift version. And then regenerate (rebalance) ring files with new `swift-ring-builder` command. And you will get the upgraded ring files.

Comment: I did try to rebalance it and I got this root@VM-Node-01:/etc/swift# swift-ring-builder account.builder rebalance
No partitions could be reassigned.
Either none need to be or none can be due to min_part_hours [1].

Comment: I also read a post which said to use write_ring to upgrade the ring.swift-ring-builder account.builder write_ring
swift-ring-builder container.builder write_ring
swift-ring-builder object.builder write_ring

Comment: Is there a way to verify the ring's version?